# jQuery : Set value of datalist?

Tags: jquery, html-datalist

```
<input list="countries" type = 'text' id='country'>
 <datalist id="countries">
    <option data-value='1' value='India'></option>
    <option data-value='2' value='USA'></option>
    <option data-value='3' value='UK'></option>
 </datalist>
```

**How do i dynamically set the value as India using jQuery or JavaScript?**

Comment: `$('#country').val('India');`

Comment: Question  not clear. You want to set value from where to where?

Comment: Usually for such kind of purpose you should use <select> dropdown...

Answer (score 5):

Actually, in Datalist, it's the input value that should be set !

When you select a value from the dropdown list, it is the value of the input which is setted to the same value as what you've selected!

so to set dynamically the value selected, it is the value of your input that should be changed!

here's an example

```js
function clickme(){
    $("#country").val("India");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="clickme()">click me</button>
<input list="countries" type = 'text' id='country'>
 <datalist id="countries">
    <option data-value='1' value='India'></option>
    <option data-value='2' value='USA'></option>
    <option data-value='3' value='UK'></option>
 </datalist>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done..

```
$('#country option').attr('selected', false).find('[value="India"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: I can put the value of input box as India but it wont get the data-value attribute which is needed.